# Bluemix running openpyxl on Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I was running python 3 on jupyte notebook, and the following code worked fine. But when i uploaded my code on Bluemix cloud, I got an error for using openpyxl. 
I notice Bluemix is using python 2 but i still don't know how to change my code accordingly. Any advice? Many thanks!!

```
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl import Workbook
```

Here is the screenshot taken from Bluemix: 
[image]

i tried "pip install openpyxl", and "!pip install openpyxl" in Bluemix Python 2. none of them are working

Comment: `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: thx! but not working though, i tried "pip install openpyxl", and "!pip install openpyxl". none of them are working

Comment: Is this for the workbook as part of Apache Spark service?

Comment: yes! its part of Apache Spark service